# Passing data from controller to model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having trouble passing data from my controller to my model using Codeigniter. I'm getting an Internal Server Error on the browser console but have narrowed it down to the issue outlined above.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
public function get_results() {
        $numOfDraws = $this->input->post('numOfDraws');
        $data = $this->lotto_model->get_results($numOfDraws);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
  public function get_results($numOfDraws)
        {
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM lotto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT "$numOfDraws"');
            return $query->result();
        }
```

If i hardcode the `LIMIT` the query works successfully. I know that `$numOfDraws` is equal to the correct value in the controller.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes around $numOfDraws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all variable injection into a string only works with double quotes, not with single quotes. Secondly your current code is open to SQL injection.

CodeIgniter provides functionality to prevent this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM lotto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?', array($numOfDraws));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is single quoted so it won't parse variables, your generated SQL would literally be:

```
SELECT * FROM lotto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT "$numOfDraws"
```

Just use CI's "ActiveRecord" class if you want cleaner syntax, abstraction, and better security:

```
public function get_results($numOfDraws)
{
    return $this->db
        ->limit($numOfDraws)
        ->order_by('id', 'DESC')
        ->get('lotto')
        ->result();
}
```

Or one way to fix your original query:

```
$query = $this->db
    ->query('SELECT * FROM lotto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.(int) $numOfDraws);
```

Comment: Using Active Record, can you tell what effect the ordering of the "rules / filters" have on the result. Let's say `$numOfDraws` is equal to 5, for example, the above looks like it would take the first 5 entries in the table, then order them - as opposed to sorting by ID first and then taking the first 5.

Comment: It's just a query builder, the order doesn't matter as long as you call `get()` last.

Answer (score 1):

Try this--

```
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM lotto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $numOfDraws");
        return $query->result();
```